# Android gridView animation

Tags: android, animation, gridview

[image]I am trying to animate the child elements in my gridView. Everything goes fine but the top row somehow seems to translate from underneath the background instead of being translated/drawn on top of the background.

xml for gridView

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#000000"> 

 <GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gameButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

The animation used on each element

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">

  <translate
    android:fromYDelta="-25%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p"
    android:duration="700"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:startOffset="50"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator" />

</set>
```

Instead of being drawn on the black bg it is somehow below the bg